# How to pick up rows from XML for processing

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

I would like to process some XML like that:

```
<rows>
 <row>
  <country>AT</country>
  <some>element</some>
 </row>
 <row>
  <country>CZ</country>
  <some>element</some>
 </row>
 <row>
  <country>BG</country>
  <some>element</some>
 </row>
 <row>
  <country>CZ</country>
  <some>element</some>
 </row>
</rows>
```

I have to regroup rows to the target XML in this way: first must be rows with country 'CZ', then can be rows with other countries.

I can pick up rows with country 'CZ' in this way:

```
<xsl:key name="countries" match="row" use="country">

<xsl:for-each select="key('countries', 'CZ')">
 <!-- do some transformation -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I don't know, how to pick up rows with other countries? Can I use somethink like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('countries', !'CZ')">
```

?

EDIT:

Expected output is:

```
<rows>
 <row>
  <country>CZ</country>
  <transformed>element</transformed>
 </row>
 <row>
  <country>CZ</country>
  <transformed>element</transformed>
 </row>
 <row>
  <country>AT</country>
  <transformed>element</transformed>
 </row>
 <row>
  <country>BG</country>
  <transformed>element</transformed>
 </row>
</rows>
```

Order of other rows (except 'CZ') is not mandatory.

I'm using XSLT 1.0, but I can use XSLT 2.0, too.

Comment: Please post the expected output, and indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without `xsl:key`.

Select CZ rows:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//row[country='CZ']"/>
```

Select other rows:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//row[country!='CZ']"/>
```

You can use the same expressions in `xsl:for-each` as well.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the most straightforward method to change the order of nodes is to **sort** them - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/rows">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row">
            <xsl:sort select="number(country='CZ')" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="some">
    <transformed>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </transformed>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, anyway... I've picked out simplier solution (I'm beginner in XSLT). +1

Comment: What makes you think it's simpler?

Comment: I'm very sorry, I cannot understand for example "@*|node()". It is my problem, I know it. But thank you very much, again!

Comment: "*I cannot understand for example "@*|node()".*" It says "identity transform" in the comment. All you need to do is lookup 'identity transform' - it has a Wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform